# Why “…, like,…”?

Tags: commas, adverbs

Can someone explain why I need to set off the adverb *like* with commas? I saw *The New Yorker* use it in [a recent article](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2023/08/28/elon-musks-shadow-rule),

> A senior defense official told me that Kahl was surprised by whom he was about to contact: “He was, like, ‘Why am I calling Elon Musk?’ ”

though I needed to double check to see whether it’s just another case of the magazine’s idiosyncratic typographical style. But then [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like) also used it in its example, and so did [Google (Oxford) Dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20like&hl=en&gl=us), who curiously did not do the same for its second example.

I find this first comma really odd. It’s not a *prosodic comma*, as far as I can tell, because no one pauses after “was” (but does after “like”). I’d also understand if it was an adverbial phrase, but it’s not! I don’t see anyone cutting off other adverbs like this either. (“She was, very, mad.” [?])

So, grammarians, why do I need the first comma?

Comment: You need the comma pair or none at all. Using like in that way, as an aside like this one, calls for a pair of commas. Such asides used to be called parenthetical expressions in that we might have set them off with **a pair of** parentheses.

Comment: This is fresh territory, but the parenthetical commas look like someone trying to apply old rules to a new invention. I would go with zero commas, since the quotation is not really a direct quotation but a characterization of someone's response or attitude. Related: [History of "I was like ..." or "I was all ..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313083/history-of-the-phrase-i-was-like-or-i-was-all)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Be like" usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212282/be-like-usage)

Answer (score 2):

In this example, *like* isn't being used as a parenthetical or discourse marker (as when, like, people, like, add it, like, to whatever they say). Instead, this is an example of the *quotative* like, in which "to be like" essentially means "to say approximately."

In the [Merriam-Webster example sentences](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like) for this sense, they use a comma only after the word "like": "so I'm like, 'Give me a break'". But in the [Cambridge page on the subject](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/like), they don't use any commas at all: "Jason was like 'I’m not going to Alma’s party because Chris is going to be there.'"

Since this usage of *like* is so informal, there isn't really a standard way of punctuating it; the only sensible option is to follow prosody, looking for the pause and change in tone that a comma usually designates. In this case, I think that most would use that change in tone after, but not before, the word "like," making Merriam-Webster's convention correct.

So why does *The New Yorker* get this wrong? I suspect it's because they confused the quotative *like* with the parenthetical *like* I mentioned earlier. That one, being a parenthetical, actually *should* be surrounded by commas on both sides.

Comment: Also, *The New Yorker* never met a punctuation mark it didn't overuse.

Comment: *Be like* doesn’t mean to say “approximately.” *So I said, “Give me a break”* and *So I go, “Give me a break”* and *So I’m like, “Give me a break”* — those are equivalent. Though you can use *be like* to express a thought or inner monologue as well as an utterance.

Comment: @TinfoilHat That comma before direct speech looks increasingly redundant. *I said she should get more recognition* has no comma while  *I said, "She should get more recognition"*  does though without a satisfactory reason.  It looks like a misinterpretation of the parenthetical commas in the insertion *"She should get more recognition," I said, "for her excellent work"*

Comment: @Henry — The satisfactory reason for the comma before direct speech in dialogue is that that is how it is done: *I said, “She should get more recognition”* If you want reported speech: *I said [that] she should get more recognition.* The interesting thing about it all is that you can’t use *was like* with reported speech. *\*I was like [that] she should get more recognition.*

Comment: +1 for *follow prosody*